# How to run multiple queries simultaneously in Node Red?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I want to run 2 queries concurrently by connecting to a single oracle DB node in Node Red. I am new to Node Red, Please help me here since my flow is not working.[image: Node red Flow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the split/join nodes these should let you inject an array of queries that will be passed to the Oracle node and then recombined afterwards.

[image]